# Is It possible to know my play store current app version in Xamarin programatically

Tags: android, xamarin

I am trying to know my current app version of play store. is there any api for that.

Answer (score 0):

No, as such there is no API for the same.

If you app uses server api, you can create an api to check for the lastest version.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your reply @gagan.

Comment: Honoured buddy!

Answer (score 0):

**For version name:**

```
Application.Context.ApplicationContext.PackageManager.GetPackageInfo(Application.Context.ApplicationContext.PackageName, 0).VersionName
```

**For version code:**

```
Application.Context.ApplicationContext.PackageManager.GetPackageInfo(Application.Context.ApplicationContext.PackageName, 0).VersionCode
```